# Imageview inside my Asynctask class is called twice

Tags: java, android, constructor, android-asynctask

I have written a program for viewpager to display images using pageradapter but I am experiencing a problem, as there are only two images that I am adding it to the list and returning the list.

I added a println to see whether the images are called properly or not and they are getting called but it is getting called twice.

```
public class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

Context mContext;
LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
public ImageView imageView;

String[] imgURLS = { "http://www.picture-newsletter.com/arctic/arctic-
         18.jpg",
        "http://www.picture-newsletter.com/arctic/arctic-20.jpg" };

public CustomPagerAdapter(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return imgURLS.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return arg0 == ((RelativeLayout) arg1);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)  
    mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_item, container, 
    false);
    imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    new LoadImage(imageView).execute();
    container.addView(itemView);
    return itemView;

}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((RelativeLayout) object);
}

}

class LoadImage extends AsyncTask<String, String, List<Bitmap>> {

Bitmap bm = null;
List<Bitmap> bmList = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
ImageView imageView;

public LoadImage(ImageView imageView) {
    System.out.println("LoadImage constructor called...");
    this.imageView = imageView;
}

@Override
protected List<Bitmap> doInBackground(String... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    URL imgUrl = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;

    try {
        imgUrl = new URL("http://www.picture-newsletter.com/arctic/arctic-
        18.jpg");
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) imgUrl.openConnection();
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.connect();
        is = conn.getInputStream();
        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);// Convert to bitmap
        bmList.add(bm);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        imgUrl = new URL("http://www.picture-newsletter.com/arctic/arctic-
        20.jpg");
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) imgUrl.openConnection();
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.connect();
        is = conn.getInputStream();
        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);// Convert to bitmap
        bmList.add(bm);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bmList;
}

protected void onPostExecute(List<Bitmap> bmList) {
    for (Bitmap bitmap : bmList) {
        System.out.println("Adding bm to imageView....");
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
    super.onPostExecute(bmList);
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

ViewPager viewPager;
 CustomPagerAdapter adapter;
//CustomAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    adapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(getBaseContext());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}

LogCat :The constructor is also getting called twice , so is the images

02-26 12:33:06.618: I/System.out(12363): LoadImage constructor called...
02-26 12:33:06.618: I/System.out(12363): LoadImage constructor called...


02-26 12:33:09.363: I/dalvikvm-heap(12363): Grow heap (frag case) to 12.238MB for 4320016-byte allocation
02-26 12:33:13.638: I/System.out(12363): Adding bm to imageView....
02-26 12:33:13.653: I/System.out(12363): Adding bm to imageView....
02-26 12:33:14.793: I/dalvikvm-heap(12363): Grow heap (frag case) to 12.239MB for 4320016-byte allocation
02-26 12:33:17.773: I/dalvikvm-heap(12363): Grow heap (frag case) to 16.359MB for 4320016-byte allocation
02-26 12:33:19.018: I/System.out(12363): Adding bm to imageView....
02-26 12:33:19.018: I/System.out(12363): Adding bm to imageView....
```

Comment: Any issue with calling twice ? because `instantiateItem` call depend on what count is return from getCount method if you add one more url in array then it will call three time

Comment: i added one more url in my string array , but still returning the same thing , as per your saying sir , the count should increase , but it is not , and why is the constructor getting called twice ? LoadImage constructor called , LoadImage constructor called

Comment: @ narahari_arjun : try to call `setOffscreenPageLimit(1)` as `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1)`

Comment: no changes sir , what does the above do , can u explain me sir ?

Comment: @ narahari_arjun :  see here [setOffscreenPageLimit](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit%28int%29)

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK sir thank you for your time , but sir can you help me in one more thing ? 
the urls i have initialized inside my array all are different , but when inside my viewpager i am scrolling horizontally , everytime same image comes , the third one , what to do sir ?

Comment: ok change `new LoadImage(imageView).execute();` to `new LoadImage(imageView).execute(imgURLS[position]);` and in  `doInBackground` use `imgUrl = new URL(params[0].toString());` to get right image

Comment: thanks alot sir , thank you , if there is any way to upvote your comment please tell me

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor and AsyncTask are called twice because

> `public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position)`

method is called twice.

How many times the above method is called depend on the **return** value of

> public int getCount()

method. In your case you are returning `imgURLS.length` which is 2.

Comment: sir , i added another url in my array but the constructor got called only twice 
02-26 13:01:48.003: I/System.out(23636): LoadImage constructor called...
02-26 13:01:48.008: I/System.out(23636): LoadImage constructor called...